# Presto - Extract Key in an Array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, amazon-athena, presto

I have this sample data (from Athena)

```
 SELECT DISTINCT m.key
  FROM (VALUES JSON '{"name":"project1","completed":false}', JSON '{"name":"project1","completed":false}',JSON '{"name":"project1","completed":false}')
     example_table(json_column)
 CROSS JOIN UNNEST (map_keys(CAST(json_column AS map<varchar,json>))) AS m(key);
 
 WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT '{"name": "Susan Smith",
           "org": "engineering",
           "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},
           {"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}'
    AS blob
)
select * from dataset
```

This will generate the below output.

```
{"name": "Susan Smith", "org": "engineering", "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false}, {"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}
```

I want to extract Key from the output.

### Expected output:

```
output
------
name
org
projects
```

Could someone help on this?

## updated:

edited this question with proper JSON.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN UNNEST (map_keys(CAST(json_column AS map<varchar,json>))) AS m(key)` that you have looks like the way. Why is it not working?

Comment: I tried it, it says . SYNTAX_ERROR: line 8:56: Cannot cast varchar(171) to map(varchar,json)

Comment: This worked actually. `CROSS JOIN UNNEST (map_keys(CAST(json_parse(blob) AS map<varchar,json>))) AS m(key)`

which means, is my column in the string?

Comment: `Cannot cast varchar(171) to map(varchar,json)` implies your column is a string (`varchar`). You can `json_parse` or `CAST(your_column AS json)`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussion in comments, this

```
map_keys(CAST(json_column AS map<varchar,json>))
```

needs to be replaced with

```
map_keys(CAST(CAST(json_column AS JSON) AS map<varchar,json>))
```